# c++ how to correctly implement parallel ifstream reading

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, constants, ifstream, file-read

First of, what I am trying to do. I have a class that can deal with a particular type of large files on storage. By dealing with it, I mean basically the following:

```
class Large {
  std::ifstream file;
  Large(const char* fname) : file(fname) { 
    // read file header, create an index of stuff that's inside, that sort of stuff
    ... 
  }

  void read_a_part(int which_part) const {
    // read from ifstream, which unfortunately modifies its state
    fstream.read(...)
  }

  ...
}
```

Now, this is all pseudo code, since I am interested in best practice and not a single particular solution. Function `read_a_state` will not compile, since it modifies the object state but is declared `const`.

In what I am trying to achieve, I am not modifying my File (I only read from it), nor am I modifying the instance of Large. Therefore all functions should be declared `const` and should also be reentrant for parallel work. It seems this cannot be done with a single `ifstream` as a member of `Large`. The solutions of not marking the file accessing member functions of `Large` as `const` or making the member `file` mutable are no good. Such solutions are not reentrant. Since `ifstream` also cannot be copied, it seems it has to be created anew for each call to `read_a_part`. Therefore, the only working solution that I see is moving `file` from being a member to being an internal variable of `read_a_part` (and most other member functions of this class). But is this a good solution performance-wise? Will thousands of calls to ifstream ctor not cause problem with the operating system? Is there not a better way?

Comment: Perhaps you should consider memory mapping your file.

Comment: Memory mapping seems like a good idea. I haven't worked with memory mapping before but yes, now that you mentioned it, it seems to make sense. I shall look into the details to see if there are any gotchas though. I mean first off, let's all assume that the file is way too big to fit in the memory.

Comment: It doesn't matter if the file is too big to fit in memory, you can still map it, and things will get swapped in and out. Of course you'll want to be careful about your reading pattern so that you don't keep "thrashing" between RAM and the disk, but you won't have the kinds of problems your question describes.

Answer (score 0):

It's slightly strange logic to make all const but not const.

For example, compiler can miss repeat calls of read operation (it will think the result will not change).

But:

- you can store into class the pointer to file variable and initialize it at constructor (const pointer);
- you can store handle on file (result of fopen function). And initialize through constructor.

H-h-hm. Good luck.

Comment: But it *is* const in the semantic sense at least. It reads from a file and does not modify the internal state of the class. ifstream having an internal state is an inconvenience in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Disks perform best on sequential access (even SSDs). Parallelizing disk I/O therefore will most likely lead to a reduction of overall throughput.

Having said that, two possible solutions:

1. Read the file sequentially then hand off the parts to a thread pool for further processing.
2. Serialize file access using a mutex:

   ```
   class Large {
     std::ifstream file;
     mutable std::mutex mtx;
   public:
     Large(const char* fname) : file(fname) { 
       // read file header, create an index of stuff that's inside, that sort of stuff
       ... 
     }

     Part read_a_part(int which_part) const {
       Part part;
       std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mtx);
       file.seekg(which_part * part_size);
       file.read(...&part...);
       return part;
     }

   }
   ```

Not sure if/why your `read_a_part()` must be `const`. If not, then you can just remove `const` and remove `mutable` from the mutex.

Comment: Well, being const is not a must, but it does signal that the class instance will not change. That is what I want to convey to the user. 
Regarding the parellelism - yes and no. Speed depends a lot on the caching implemented in the OS. If the usage pattern of the contents is right, they might still all get cached and everything can very well run in parallel at full tilt. Even if that was not the case it should be faster to put the IO operations in queue on the OS level than protecting them with mutex on the user level.

Comment: Therefore, while `mutex` is a solution and I like the `mutable mutex` idea, I still believe that there must be a better way. BTW, `file` should be mutable in the presented case too.

Answer (score 0):

I am answering my own question since the answer is no, there is hardly a *perfect* solution. So, for the reference, I list several tradeoff solutions, that I have considered:

- Memory mapping the file. This is not supported within the C or C++ standards, but it is by POSIX. It can be used without much problem on all major operating systems, but through a 3rd party lib.
- Accepting that all file access comes with a state. State is not const even when only reading is performed, and file reading functions are not reentrant by default. Therefore thread safety measures must be taken.
- Using throw-away objects. Every time file is accessed. a new handle is obtained (a new ifstream is opened), a part of file is read, and then the handle is discarded. The function that wraps the reading part is reentrant and holds no state. No external dependencies are required.

I opted so use the last solutions. It is not the most efficient of solutions, but it is the simplest one.